# Pointer or reference variables are not given a name when defining function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I got a code like this

```
int def_function(typeA *, double &) {}
```

Could you please explain what is the meaning of these variables, why they have types but do not have name?

Comment: The variable name can be omitted if they are not used in place (in header files, for example), but I strongly recommend not to do this because it decrease the readability of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature says that there is a function name `def_function` which take two parameters of type  `'pointer of typeA '` and `'reference of double'` . The name of parameter variables are optional but if there is no name then in function definition you can't refer or use any of these variables. So if you are not using those variables in your function you can omit parameter name otherwise it is required.

```
int def_function(typeA *, double &)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this function, none of the arguments are used. So that there is no need to name them.

Meaning of those variables are:

- `typeA *` pointer to an object of type `typeA`
- `double &` reference of an object of type `double`. Means that, a "double" will be passed by its non-const reference, i.e. it may be changed.

Answer (score 1):

C++14 standard section 8.3.5.11 says that:

> **An identifier can optionally be provided as a parameter name; if
>   present in a function definition (8.4), it names a parameter
>   (sometimes called “formal argument”).  Note: In particular, parameter
>   names are also optional in function definitions** and names used for a
>   parameter in different declarations and the definition of a function
>   need not be the same.

Remember this is different in C. In C it is mandatory to give a name to formal. parameter.

C99 standard says that:

> [6.9.1.5] If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the
>   declaration of each parameter shall include an identifier, except for
>   the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single parameter
>   of type void, in which case there shall not be an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to name the function arguments at function definition and when you use these variables.
- You don't have to name the arguments at function declaration if it's defined later.
- You don't have to name arguments that you are not using.